# How do I create a simple callback in static classes in c#

Tags: c#, callback, portable-class-library, static-classes

I have a static class that has a method that again calls two other static class methods

Basically In the first static class I want to know once the operation is done in the two other static classes

```
 public static class FirstClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FirstClassMethod() 
        {
            SecondClass. SecondClassMethod();
            ThirdClass. ThirdClassMethod();
        }
 }

 public static class SecondClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SecondClassMethod() 
        {

        }
 }

 public static class ThirdClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ThirdClassMethod() 
        {

        }
 }
```

Any help on solving my problem would be appreciated very much

Comment: Is there a special reason why you did not await any of the two methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `Task.WhenAll`, you can create a single task that wraps several tasks and completes when all wrapped tasks are completed.

```
 public static class FirstClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task FirstClassMethod() 
        {
            return await Task.WhenAll(
                SecondClass.SecondClassMethod(),
                ThirdClass.ThirdClassMethod()
            );
        }
 }

 public static class SecondClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task SecondClassMethod() 
        {

        }
 }

 public static class ThirdClass{

    public static async System.Threading.Tasks.Task ThirdClassMethod() 
        {

        }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

With the `await` keyword your waiting until the `Task` is done.

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

public static async Task FirstClassMethod() 
{
    await SecondClass. SecondClassMethod();
    await ThirdClass. ThirdClassMethod();
    ...
}
```

BTW:

> You should consider not using await only if you're sure that you don't want to wait for the asynchronous call to complete and that the called method won't raise any exceptions.

Comment: if I don't use await to call async task , will it not throw any error... Correct me If I am wrong

Comment: If I don't use await , then ThirdClassMethod can continue its execution before SecondClassMethod finishes

Comment: @RajanM Even if you don't use await it can throw an exception but if you want to catch it you need to do something like this `task.ContinueWith(t => HandleError(t.Exception),
    TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted);.`. If you use await you can catch it normaly.

Comment: @RajanM the second statement is correct but the point is that somewhen you have to wait for the task to compleate. If you do not know when stuff is done and the process could shut down before all tasks are done.